# IIS Downloading Application Instead of Displaying

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS 7

In IIS > Sites There is an (ASP) application that's bound to port 8080, when I visit `localhost:8080` a file is downloaded instead of the page being displayed.The file appears to be the whole application?

The site is located at `wwwroot/example` and within here there are various `.dll` files, folders and a `web.config`.

It was working until I changed something in the sites root `web.config` file, I didn't make a backup of this so I can't recall exactly what was there although I know it was approx 6 -8 lines.

I didn't change any server settings or bindings. I have restarted the main IIS server and the site itself a few times. There are other sites hosted on the same server and they are working as expected. I've tried various browsers.

I have checked windows features and roles and can confirm that `ASP.NET 3.5` and `ASP.NET 4.5` are displaying as `(Installed)`.

I have very little experience with IIS or ASP. A few questions;

- Why is the application being downloaded rather than displayed?
- Can I recreate the `web.config` file if this is the issue?
- How can I begin to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

The application being downloaded rather than displayed should be that you did not add asp.net feature, In "Turn Windows Features On or Off" > "Internet Information Services" > "World Wide Web Services" > "Application Development Features" > "ASP.NET 4.8" then click on "OK" to install the feature. After the feature installation, restart your system.

[image]

Comment: thanks for this @samwu but I can confirm that `ASP.NET 4.5` is displaying as `(Installed)`. Have you any other ideas?

Comment: Could you please advise the error message and iis log that you get?

Answer (score 0):

For us it was a binding issue. If you open IIS and right click the website and look at binding properties it will list all the names and how it will treat the files.

There were two entries we needed to delete:

```
type                 host  port       binding
------------------------------------------------
net.msmq                              localhost*
msmq.formatname                       localhost*
```

The remaining binding that needed to stay was:

```
type    host      port                 binding
------------------------------------------------
http              80
```

When hostname is blank, it means it will match anything- however because the two entries were there catching queries to localhost first, it never was able to handle the request as type http.